# Independent serial for each foreign key value

Tags: postgresql

I have a table shared by many different users called *players* and a table called *users*.

Each player has the primary key *id* (serial) and a foreign key called *owner_id* which matches to *users.id*.

In order for users to update their players in my database (through my API) they must specify the same id as appears in the players table (the ids are visible to them!).

Because it's shared, the player ids that one user creates might look like:

```
1
2
12
56
```

(with the gaps being the id's used by players created by other users).

How can I create a new column called *local_id* which will behave like an independent serial on each *owner_id* value?

So each user would see the *local_id* as perfectly incrementing every time they create a new player?

```
1
2
3
4
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with `SERIAL`.

You could create a `SEQUENCE` for each `owner_id` but that'd be painful and scale poorly.

Instead, use a counter table where each `owner_id` has a separate counter, and

```
update players_per_user_counter 
set next_val = next_val + 1 
where player_id = $1 
returning next_val
```

to get new identifiers. For more info search for "PostgreSQL gapless sequence".

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/9984196/398670